# How to redirect URL by id in PHP while inserting data into database

Tags: php, sweetalert

This is my code of inserting data into database. so i want redirect to other page by clients_id in URL.so i can access in other page.

```php
if(isset($_POST['upload_product'])) {

    $clients_id = $_POST['clients_id'];
    $_SESSION['clients_id'] = $clients_id;
    $get_product = "INSERT into tb_product(product_description,product_quantity,hsn_code,remarks,price,tracking_id,dc_no,clients_id) Values('$product_description','$product_quantity','$hsn_code','$remarks','$price','$tracking_id','$dc_no','$clients_id')";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$get_product))
    {

        ?>
        <script>
            swal({
            title: "Congratulations!",
            text: "Products Added Successfully",
            type: "success",
            timer: 2000,
            showConfirmButton: false
            }, function(){

            // header("Location: ClientsProductList.php?clients_id=".urlencode($current_id['id']);

            window.location.href = 'ClientsProductList.php??clients_id='.$_SESSION['clients_id'];
            });
        </script>
        <?php

    } else {
        echo "Error in registering...Please try again later!";
        echo "Error!".$get_product."<br>". mysqli_error($con);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line:

```
window.location.href = 'ClientsProductList.php??clients_id='.$_SESSION['clients_id'];
```

to:

```
window.location.href = 'ClientsProductList.php?clients_id='.<?php echo $_SESSION['clients_id']; ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

For redirection you can use JavaScript or directly you can use php also 
Like this.

```php
header('location:ClientsProductList.php?Id=' . $clients_id);
```

or in JavaScript

```js
window.location.assign('ClientsProductList.php?id=' + clientid)
```